# NTL Library ref_GF2 Run-time Error

Tags: c++, ntl

I am using the NTL C++ Library. On trying to execute the following code:

```
NTL::ref_GF2 *zero = new NTL::ref_GF2();
NTL::ref_GF2 *one = new NTL::ref_GF2();
set(*one);
```

I am getting an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error:

```
ref_GF2 operator=(long a)
{
   unsigned long rval = a & 1;
   unsigned long lval = *_ref_GF2__ptr;
   lval = (lval & ~(1UL << _ref_GF2__pos)) | (rval << _ref_GF2__pos);
   *_ref_GF2__ptr = lval;
   return *this;
}
```

The problem seems to stem from the set(*one) line of code.

I've been trying to understand what's going wrong in the code, to no avail. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/GF2.cpp.html):

> The header file for GF2 also declares the class `ref_GF2`, which
>   use used to represent *non-const references* to `GF2`'s, [...].
>
> There are implicit conversions from `ref_GF2` to `const GF2`
>   and from `GF2&` to `ref_GF2`.

You get the error because your are defining a reference without a target.
At the point where you call `set(*one)`, `*one` does not point to a `GF2` and so it throws an error.

It works fine, if you point to a `GF2` before calling `set(*one)`:

```
NTL::GF2 x = GF2();
NTL::set(x);               // x = 1

NTL::ref_GF2 *zero = new NTL::ref_GF2(x);
NTL::ref_GF2 *one  = new NTL::ref_GF2(x);

// this works now
NTL::clear(*zero);
NTL::set(*one);

cout << *zero << endl;     // prints "1"
cout << *one << endl;      // prints "1"
```

Notice that `ref_GF2` represents a reference to a `GF2`. My example code shows that zero and one both point to `x`. Maybe you want to use `GF2` instead of `ref_GF2`.

Comment: Hey, just solved this as well. You are right, I had to use GF2 instead of ref_GF2. Thanks for the feedback!